# Prevent account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com from redirecting to microsoftonline.com?

Tags: firefox, redirection, azure

For reasons related to a project I'm working on, I need to be able to plug in https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com into Firefox without it redirecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com (or anything else, for that matter). Even disabling redirects in Firefox or using extensions like SkipRedirect don't seem to help. Is there a way to put the windowsazure.com into Firefox and have it *stay* there?

Thanks in advance to the community for all of their help!

Comment: You cannot control what redirects happen on a server that you have zero control

Comment: How does the windows azure redirect differ from a redirect on any other website? Other sites seem more responsive to my efforts at preventing redirects.